# How to apply pytorch tril to a batch, passing different diagonal parameter to each batch element?

Tags: python, vector, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I want to write custom Pytorch loss function.
It recieves two batches:

1. batch of square matrices
2. batch of ints

For each matrix in batch 1. I want to apply `torch.tril(matrix, diagonal=d)`, where diagonal d is corresponding element in batch 2.

However torch does not allow me to pass a vector as diagonal parameter

I can not use for loop to apply tril element-wise, because it will be impossible to calculate gradient.

So I need some vector pytorch operation, that does the same as tril, but can receive tensor as diagonal parameter

Is there any way to perform described above operation in pytorch?

Here I designed a toy example of batches of 2 element

```
import torch
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50], [100,200,300,400,500], 
                       [31,23,33,43,53], [21,22,23,24,25]])
matrix2 = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50], [100,200,300,400,500], [100,200,300,400,500], 
                       [31,23,33,43,53], [21,22,23,24,25]])
matrix_batch = torch.Tensor([matrix, matrix2])
diagonals = torch.Tensor([-1, -2])
```

I expect recieve the following tensor:

```
result = torch.Tensor(
      [[[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [100., 200.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 31.,  23.,  33.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,   0.]], 
       [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [100.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 31.,  23.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 21.,  22.,  23.,   0.,   0.]]])
```

Comment: Making `matrix_batch = matrix_batch.float().requires_grad_()` differentiable you can use  `torch.stack([torch.tril(x, int(y)) for x,y in zip(matrix_batch, diagonals)])` to keep a computable gradient. Currently `functorch.vmap` [doesn't support](https://github.com/pytorch/functorch/issues/1088) mapping non tensor inputs and `torch.tril` doesn't support tensors as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [10,20,30,40,50], [100,200,300,400,500], 
                       [31,23,33,43,53], [21,22,23,24,25]])
matrix2 = np.array([[10,20,30,40,50], [100,200,300,400,500], [100,200,300,400,500], 
                       [31,23,33,43,53], [21,22,23,24,25]])
matrix_batch = torch.Tensor([matrix, matrix2])
diagonals = torch.Tensor([-1, -2])

def prueba(matrix_batch, diagonals):
    return torch.stack([ torch.tril(matrix_batch[i], diagonal=int(diagonals[i].item())) for i in range(len(diagonals)) ])

print(prueba(matrix_batch, diagonals))
```

The problem is this is extremely slow

```
UserWarning: Creating a tensor from a list of numpy.ndarrays is extremely slow. Please consider converting the list to a single numpy.ndarray with numpy.array() before converting to a tensor. (Triggered internally at ..\torch\csrc\utils\tensor_new.cpp:248.)
  matrix_batch = torch.Tensor([matrix, matrix2])
tensor([[[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 10.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [100., 200.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 31.,  23.,  33.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,   0.]],

        [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [100.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 31.,  23.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [ 21.,  22.,  23.,   0.,   0.]]])
```